# I want to create tabs to change month name in a div - image attached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create something like this right and left tabs that change the month name when clicked. what I can do? I tried google but I don't know what this is called. I have created a simple HTML using buttons and now what I want is to when I click on the right button month changes from *Jan* to *Feb* and then click on left button month changes from *Feb* to *Jan* some for other months in a year.

[image]

### HTML code

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs div.month {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}

.left button,
.right button {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabs button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right button {
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
}

.left button {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
}

.month input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 35px
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="left">
    <button type="button" name="left"> < </button>
  </div>
  <div class="month">
    <input type="text" name="" id="month" value="Jan" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button" name="right"> > </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your coding trial for this.

Comment: One way to get started is to find a site that has this sort of layout, enter your browser's dev tools inspect facility and see how they have laid things out and what CSS they have applied. Then have a go yourself and if stuck put your code so far into the question and describe what isn't working.

Comment: You have to create a handler function for this. In this function, you could have an array containing all of the months and another constant containing the selected current index. When one of the buttons is clicked you should increase or decrease the value of the index and use this array and the index to always display the proper month.

Comment: I am not good at javascript can you share some links ?

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>month</title>
  <style media="screen">
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .tab-wrapper {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabs {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background: #eee;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .tabs div.month {
      width: 4em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .left button, .right button{
      padding: 4px 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      background: transparent;
    }
    .tabs button {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 0;
    }
    .right button {
      border-left: 1px solid white;
    }
    .left button{
      border-right: 1px solid white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="left">
        <button type="button"> < </button>
      </div>
      <div class="month" data-month-index="0">Jan</div>
      <div class="right">
        <button type="button"> > </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="left">
        <button type="button"> < </button>
      </div>
      <div class="month" data-month-index="0">Jan</div>
      <div class="right">
        <button type="button"> > </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    const months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    const handleButtonClick = (evt) => {
        const clickLeft = evt.target.closest('div').classList.contains('left')
        const displayMonth = evt.target.closest('.tabs').querySelector('.month')
        let index = Number(displayMonth.dataset.monthIndex)
        if (clickLeft)
            index = index - (index > 0 ? 1 : 0)
        else
            index = index + (index < months.length - 1 ? 1 : 0)
        displayMonth.dataset.monthIndex = index
        displayMonth.innerHTML = months[index]
    }
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs button').forEach(b => {
      b.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick)
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

var curMonth = 0;

function onRightClick() {
  let ele = document.getElementById("month");
  if(curMonth < 11)
    curMonth++;
  ele.value  = months[curMonth];
}

function onLeftClick() {
  let ele = document.getElementById("month");
  if(curMonth > 0)
    curMonth--;
  ele.value  = months[curMonth];
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs div.month {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}

.left button,
.right button {
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabs button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right button {
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
}

.left button {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
}

.month input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 35px
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="left">
    <button type="button" name="left" onclick="onLeftClick()"> < </button>
  </div>
  <div class="month">
    <input type="text" name="" id="month" value=Jan disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <button type="button" name="right" onclick="onRightClick()"> > </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

let curMonth = 0;

function next() {
  const ele = document.querySelector(".month span");
  if (curMonth < 11)
    curMonth++;
  ele.textContent  = months[curMonth];
}

function prev() {
  const ele = document.querySelector(".month span");
  if (curMonth > 0)
    curMonth--;
  ele.textContent  = months[curMonth];
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial, serif;
}

.tab-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}

.tabs {
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

.tabs div.month {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  flex: 1;
}

.month span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
}

.left button,
.right button {
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: none;
}

.tabs button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right button {
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #eee;
}

.left button {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  border-right: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />

<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="left">
      <button type="button" name="left" onclick="prev()"> < </button>
    </div>
    <div class="month">
      <span>Jan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <button type="button" name="right" onclick="next()"> > </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.. but this the desing I want to change month name when button clicked

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have misunderstood the question. I have now updated the answer.